# How to set a Javascript source file working in Javascript print function

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have following Javascript code included as Javascript source file to print table header on every printed page (by the printer). I have added the table.js file in the code snippet in order to keep my question smaller. Please look at code snippet if you want the table.js code

**script: table.js**

```js
(function() { // THIS FUNCTION IS REQUIRED.
if(/Firefox|MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
  var formatForPrint = function(table) {
    var noBreak = document.createElement("div")
      , noBreakTable = noBreak.appendChild(document.createElement("div")).appendChild(table.cloneNode())
      , tableParent = table.parentNode
      , tableParts = table.children
      , partCount = tableParts.length
      , partNum = 0
      , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
    noBreak.className = "noBreak";
    for(; partNum < partCount; partNum++) {
      if(!/tbody/i.test(tableParts[partNum].tagName))
        noBreakTable.appendChild(tableParts[partNum].cloneNode(true));
    }
    if(cell) {
      noBreakTable.appendChild(cell.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode()).appendChild(cell.parentNode.cloneNode(true));
      if(!table.tHead) {
        var borderRow = document.createElement("tr");
        borderRow.appendChild(document.createElement("th")).colSpan="1000";
        borderRow.className = "borderRow";
        table.insertBefore(document.createElement("thead"), table.tBodies[0]).appendChild(borderRow);
      }
    }
    tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), table).style.paddingTop = ".009px";
    tableParent.insertBefore(noBreak, table);
  };
else
  var formatForPrint = function(table) {
    var tableParent = table.parentNode
      , cell = table.querySelector("tbody > tr > td");
    if(cell) {
      var topFauxRow = document.createElement("table")
        , fauxRowTable = topFauxRow.insertRow(0).insertCell(0).appendChild(table.cloneNode())
        , colgroup = fauxRowTable.appendChild(document.createElement("colgroup"))
        , headerHider = document.createElement("div")
        , metricsRow = document.createElement("tr")
        , cells = cell.parentNode.cells
        , cellNum = cells.length
        , colCount = 0
        , tbods = table.tBodies
        , tbodCount = tbods.length
        , tbodNum = 0
        , tbod = tbods[0];
      for(; cellNum--; colCount += cells[cellNum].colSpan);
      for(cellNum = colCount; cellNum--; metricsRow.appendChild(document.createElement("td")).style.padding = 0);
      cells = metricsRow.cells;
      tbod.insertBefore(metricsRow, tbod.firstChild);
      for(; ++cellNum < colCount; colgroup.appendChild(document.createElement("col")).style.width = cells[cellNum].offsetWidth + "px");
      var borderWidth = metricsRow.offsetHeight;
      metricsRow.className = "metricsRow";
      borderWidth -= metricsRow.offsetHeight;
      tbod.removeChild(metricsRow);
      tableParent.insertBefore(topFauxRow, table).className = "fauxRow";
      if(table.tHead)
        fauxRowTable.appendChild(table.tHead);
      var fauxRow = topFauxRow.cloneNode(true)
        , fauxRowCell = fauxRow.rows[0].cells[0];
      fauxRowCell.insertBefore(headerHider, fauxRowCell.firstChild).style.marginBottom = -fauxRowTable.offsetHeight - borderWidth + "px";
      if(table.caption)
        fauxRowTable.insertBefore(table.caption, fauxRowTable.firstChild);
      if(tbod.rows[0])
        fauxRowTable.appendChild(tbod.cloneNode()).appendChild(tbod.rows[0]);
      for(; tbodNum < tbodCount; tbodNum++) {
        tbod = tbods[tbodNum];
        rows = tbod.rows;
        for(; rows[0]; tableParent.insertBefore(fauxRow.cloneNode(true), table).rows[0].cells[0].children[1].appendChild(tbod.cloneNode()).appendChild(rows[0]));
      }
      tableParent.removeChild(table);
    }


    else
      tableParent.insertBefore(document.createElement("div"), table).appendChild(table).parentNode.className="fauxRow";
  };


var tables = document.body.querySelectorAll("table.print")
  , tableNum = tables.length;
for(; tableNum--; formatForPrint(tables[tableNum]));
})();

function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printDiv('content')" />
<div id="content"><table><thead><tr><th>Serial Number</th><th>Number</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>1000</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>1001</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>1002</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>1003</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>1004</td></tr><tr><td>6</td><td>1005</td></tr><tr><td>7</td><td>1006</td></tr><tr><td>8</td><td>1007</td></tr><tr><td>9</td><td>1008</td></tr><tr><td>10</td><td>1009</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>1010</td></tr><tr><td>12</td><td>1011</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>1012</td></tr><tr><td>14</td><td>1013</td></tr><tr><td>15</td><td>1014</td></tr><tr><td>16</td><td>1015</td></tr><tr><td>17</td><td>1016</td></tr><tr><td>18</td><td>1017</td></tr><tr><td>19</td><td>1018</td></tr><tr><td>20</td><td>1019</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td>1020</td></tr><tr><td>22</td><td>1021</td></tr><tr><td>23</td><td>1022</td></tr><tr><td>24</td><td>1023</td></tr><tr><td>25</td><td>1024</td></tr><tr><td>26</td><td>1025</td></tr><tr><td>27</td><td>1026</td></tr><tr><td>28</td><td>1027</td></tr><tr><td>29</td><td>1028</td></tr><tr><td>30</td><td>1029</td></tr><tr><td>31</td><td>1030</td></tr><tr><td>32</td><td>1031</td></tr><tr><td>33</td><td>1032</td></tr><tr><td>34</td><td>1033</td></tr><tr><td>35</td><td>1034</td></tr><tr><td>36</td><td>1035</td></tr><tr><td>37</td><td>1036</td></tr><tr><td>38</td><td>1037</td></tr><tr><td>39</td><td>1038</td></tr><tr><td>40</td><td>1039</td></tr><tr><td>41</td><td>1040</td></tr><tr><td>42</td><td>1041</td></tr><tr><td>43</td><td>1042</td></tr><tr><td>44</td><td>1043</td></tr><tr><td>45</td><td>1044</td></tr><tr><td>46</td><td>1045</td></tr><tr><td>47</td><td>1046</td></tr><tr><td>48</td><td>1047</td></tr><tr><td>49</td><td>1048</td></tr><tr><td>50</td><td>1049</td></tr><tr><td>51</td><td>1050</td></tr><tr><td>52</td><td>1051</td></tr><tr><td>53</td><td>1052</td></tr><tr><td>54</td><td>1053</td></tr><tr><td>55</td><td>1054</td></tr><tr><td>56</td><td>1055</td></tr><tr><td>57</td><td>1056</td></tr><tr><td>58</td><td>1057</td></tr><tr><td>59</td><td>1058</td></tr><tr><td>60</td><td>1059</td></tr><tr><td>61</td><td>1060</td></tr><tr><td>62</td><td>1061</td></tr><tr><td>63</td><td>1062</td></tr><tr><td>64</td><td>1063</td></tr><tr><td>65</td><td>1064</td></tr><tr><td>66</td><td>1065</td></tr><tr><td>67</td><td>1066</td></tr><tr><td>68</td><td>1067</td></tr><tr><td>69</td><td>1068</td></tr><tr><td>70</td><td>1069</td></tr><tr><td>71</td><td>1070</td></tr><tr><td>72</td><td>1071</td></tr><tr><td>73</td><td>1072</td></tr><tr><td>74</td><td>1073</td></tr><tr><td>75</td><td>1074</td></tr><tr><td>76</td><td>1075</td></tr><tr><td>77</td><td>1076</td></tr><tr><td>78</td><td>1077</td></tr><tr><td>79</td><td>1078</td></tr><tr><td>80</td><td>1079</td></tr><tr><td>81</td><td>1080</td></tr><tr><td>82</td><td>1081</td></tr><tr><td>83</td><td>1082</td></tr><tr><td>84</td><td>1083</td></tr><tr><td>85</td><td>1084</td></tr><tr><td>86</td><td>1085</td></tr><tr><td>87</td><td>1086</td></tr><tr><td>88</td><td>1087</td></tr><tr><td>89</td><td>1088</td></tr><tr><td>90</td><td>1089</td></tr><tr><td>91</td><td>1090</td></tr><tr><td>92</td><td>1091</td></tr><tr><td>93</td><td>1092</td></tr><tr><td>94</td><td>1093</td></tr><tr><td>95</td><td>1094</td></tr><tr><td>96</td><td>1095</td></tr><tr><td>97</td><td>1096</td></tr><tr><td>98</td><td>1097</td></tr><tr><td>99</td><td>1098</td></tr><tr><td>100</td><td>1099</td></tr><tr><td>101</td><td>1100</td></tr><tr><td>102</td><td>1101</td></tr><tr><td>103</td><td>1102</td></tr><tr><td>104</td><td>1103</td></tr><tr><td>105</td><td>1104</td></tr><tr><td>106</td><td>1105</td></tr><tr><td>107</td><td>1106</td></tr><tr><td>108</td><td>1107</td></tr><tr><td>109</td><td>1108</td></tr><tr><td>110</td><td>1109</td></tr><tr><td>111</td><td>1110</td></tr><tr><td>112</td><td>1111</td></tr><tr><td>113</td><td>1112</td></tr><tr><td>114</td><td>1113</td></tr><tr><td>115</td><td>1114</td></tr><tr><td>116</td><td>1115</td></tr><tr><td>117</td><td>1116</td></tr><tr><td>118</td><td>1117</td></tr><tr><td>119</td><td>1118</td></tr><tr><td>120</td><td>1119</td></tr><tr><td>121</td><td>1120</td></tr><tr><td>122</td><td>1121</td></tr><tr><td>123</td><td>1122</td></tr><tr><td>124</td><td>1123</td></tr><tr><td>125</td><td>1124</td></tr><tr><td>126</td><td>1125</td></tr><tr><td>127</td><td>1126</td></tr><tr><td>128</td><td>1127</td></tr><tr><td>129</td><td>1128</td></tr><tr><td>130</td><td>1129</td></tr><tr><td>131</td><td>1130</td></tr><tr><td>132</td><td>1131</td></tr><tr><td>133</td><td>1132</td></tr><tr><td>134</td><td>1133</td></tr><tr><td>135</td><td>1134</td></tr><tr><td>136</td><td>1135</td></tr><tr><td>137</td><td>1136</td></tr><tr><td>138</td><td>1137</td></tr><tr><td>139</td><td>1138</td></tr><tr><td>140</td><td>1139</td></tr><tr><td>141</td><td>1140</td></tr><tr><td>142</td><td>1141</td></tr><tr><td>143</td><td>1142</td></tr><tr><td>144</td><td>1143</td></tr><tr><td>145</td><td>1144</td></tr><tr><td>146</td><td>1145</td></tr><tr><td>147</td><td>1146</td></tr><tr><td>148</td><td>1147</td></tr><tr><td>149</td><td>1148</td></tr><tr><td>150</td><td>1149</td></tr><tr><td>151</td><td>1150</td></tr><tr><td>152</td><td>1151</td></tr><tr><td>153</td><td>1152</td></tr><tr><td>154</td><td>1153</td></tr><tr><td>155</td><td>1154</td></tr><tr><td>156</td><td>1155</td></tr><tr><td>157</td><td>1156</td></tr><tr><td>158</td><td>1157</td></tr><tr><td>159</td><td>1158</td></tr><tr><td>160</td><td>1159</td></tr><tr><td>161</td><td>1160</td></tr><tr><td>162</td><td>1161</td></tr><tr><td>163</td><td>1162</td></tr><tr><td>164</td><td>1163</td></tr><tr><td>165</td><td>1164</td></tr><tr><td>166</td><td>1165</td></tr><tr><td>167</td><td>1166</td></tr><tr><td>168</td><td>1167</td></tr><tr><td>169</td><td>1168</td></tr><tr><td>170</td><td>1169</td></tr><tr><td>171</td><td>1170</td></tr><tr><td>172</td><td>1171</td></tr><tr><td>173</td><td>1172</td></tr><tr><td>174</td><td>1173</td></tr><tr><td>175</td><td>1174</td></tr><tr><td>176</td><td>1175</td></tr><tr><td>177</td><td>1176</td></tr><tr><td>178</td><td>1177</td></tr><tr><td>179</td><td>1178</td></tr><tr><td>180</td><td>1179</td></tr><tr><td>181</td><td>1180</td></tr><tr><td>182</td><td>1181</td></tr><tr><td>183</td><td>1182</td></tr><tr><td>184</td><td>1183</td></tr><tr><td>185</td><td>1184</td></tr><tr><td>186</td><td>1185</td></tr><tr><td>187</td><td>1186</td></tr><tr><td>188</td><td>1187</td></tr><tr><td>189</td><td>1188</td></tr><tr><td>190</td><td>1189</td></tr><tr><td>191</td><td>1190</td></tr><tr><td>192</td><td>1191</td></tr><tr><td>193</td><td>1192</td></tr><tr><td>194</td><td>1193</td></tr><tr><td>195</td><td>1194</td></tr><tr><td>196</td><td>1195</td></tr><tr><td>197</td><td>1196</td></tr><tr><td>198</td><td>1197</td></tr><tr><td>199</td><td>1198</td></tr><tr><td>200</td><td>1199</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

I add this javascript code as source file in php page like this:

```
<?php
$sn = 1; $num = 1000;
echo '<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printDiv(\'content\')" />
echo '<div id="content">';
//creating lot of rows so that it will be printed on more than one page
echo '<table><thead><tr><th>Serial Number</th><th>Number</th></tr><tbody>';
for($i=0;$i<200;$i++){
 echo '<tr><td>'.$sn+$i.'</td><td>'.$num+$i.'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
echo '<script src="table.js"></script>'; //<--- table.js file
echo '</div>';
?>
```

and the javascript code for print the table is:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
  }
```

the included table.js file works great by this method the table header is repeated on every printed page. But it adds some additional div, table, tbody etc to the main table for formatting the table by the table.js file.

This is creating some problem if I add some feature like add row, delete row etc after creating the table and thereby reordering serial number column. 
That's why I want at first the table will not be formatted, no additional div, table, tbody etc will be added to the main table by the table.js code. So I have omitted the below line from the php page:

```
'<script src="table.js"></script>'; //<--- table.js file
```

But I want when I press "print" button, the whole code of table.js file will be in action and table will be formatted (necessary div, addtional table, tbody etc will be added to the main table to print table headers on every printed page) before printing. But I cannot figure out how to do it. I tried the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  script.setAttribute('src', 'table.js');
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
  }
</script>
```

But seems the js file is not working, i.e table header is not printing on every printed page.
Do you have any idea, how the javascript code of table.js can be added in such way that it will work only after pressing "Print" button?

[note: I know that the way I am printing have some limitations/demerits and should not print webpage by this way. But I have to do it for some reasons. So please don't make any argument for changing Javascript print(div) function]

Comment: I see a lot of text and code and honestly it made me go bleh... Could you shorten down your question without sacrificing understanding and clarity? Exclude text that doesn't concern the question / issue.

Comment: I have added the table.js in code snippet in order to keep my question shorter. Please review my question now.

Comment: as far as I understand the question, you need to have a different print view than the screen view? right?

Comment: No, it's not. I want to add javascript source file inside an javascript function

Comment: Don't output HTML from PHP using multiple `echo`s like what is being done. Instead, close the `<?php` tag, output "raw" HTML, and reopen it where you need code, including loops and variable `echo`s. The result will be the same and the core more readable.

Comment: lol.....some people always more interested in giving suggestion rather than giving solutions. Do you have any idea how to create 200 numbers of rows in 3 lines of code in plane html code? If I had posted a table of 200 rows in html here somebody told that my question is too long and messy (one person told already in this post when I posted table.js at first). By the way, you didn't give me any suggestion on solving my main problem.